# Prevent users from deleting files uploaded Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, document-management, content-management-system

I've been testing Alfresco for a few days but seem not to find a solution for this.

In Alfresco when an user uploads a file to a folder where it has the contributor role everything works nice, but he can delete that file. I want avoid that so I have defined a rule that takes the ownership of every file uploaded. The script is defined as

```
document.setOwner('admin');
```

This way the file can be deleted only by admin. If the rule is active the upload fails for everyother user. Does anybody know what it takes to take ownership of a file in that situation using a script?

I am using Alfresco 4.0a

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not just altering the permissions on the folder to remove the delete rights?

Comment: I don't know exactly where that option is? Do you?

Comment: I don't think there's a simple UI to do it, instead you'll need to tweak the config. See [this](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Security_and_Authentication#The_default_permission_model_and_simple_extensions) and [this](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Custom_Permissions_in_Share) to get you started

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can better do the following

```
document.setOwner("");
```

Because admin already has full authority in Alfresco.